# Page redirects incorrectly if a user is logged in

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently working on a login functionality of a web application.

I have the "Login Page" when I load the `http://localhost:8080/test/`, which can only be accessed if a user is not logged in.
Once the user is successfully logged in, he should now see the "Welcome Page" on `http://localhost:8080/test/welcome`, displaying a "Name" link.
Clicking the "Name" link should go to `http://localhost:8080/test/welcome/name`.
If the user have not logged out but visited the `http://localhost:8080/test/`, he should be redirected to "Welcome Page".

*(The function is like the Facebook app. If you haven't logged out on Tab 1, you can still view your News Feed if you visited Facebook on Tab 2 of your browser.)*

Here's the problem. While logged in, I'm able to load the "Welcome Page" when I visited `http://localhost:8080/test/`.
However, when I clicked on the "Name" link on the "Welcome Page", I was just redirected to `http://localhost:8080/test/welcome`, which is the link for the "Welcome Page". It seems that it just reloaded the page.

Here are some code sample:

**Login.tsx**

```
<Switch>
    {checkLoginUserId() != null ?
        <Redirect to="/welcome" />
        : <Redirect to="/" />}
</Switch>
<Route path="/welcome" component={Welcome} />
<Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
```

**Welcome.tsx**

```
<Route exact={true} path="/welcome" component={Welcome} />
<Route path="/welcome/name" component={Name} />
```

I don't know why it goes to the other route. It seems that the answer to my problem is very easy but I cannot pinpoint the culprit.

Comment: What does your Link look like ?

Comment: What is `checkLoginUserId()` function returning ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you'd be passing the actual name in the `to` prop of `Link` tag like 
 `to="/welcome/abc"`

Change your route in `Welcome.tsx` to this

```
<Route path="/welcome/:name" component={Name} /> //:name accepts any name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Add you condition inside the `render` prop of `Route`. Also, add the Route inside the switch.

```
 <Switch>
   <Route
     exact
     path="/welcome/:name"
     render={props => checkLoginUserId() != null ? (<Redirect to="/welcome" />) : (<Login {...props} />)}
  />
```